# JavaScript array to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have written a simple JS script, that saves mouse positions in an array, which I then send to a php function via AJAX. It works, and saves the recieved data, but the problem is how it is saved, i.e. i would expect to have a normal output of the x and y position as is: [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],...

But what i get is something like this:
a:63:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:527;i:1;i:1010;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:490;i:1;i:1205;}i:2;a:2:{i:0;i:588;i:1;i:1311;}i:3;a:2:{i:0;i:615;i:1;i:1368;}i:4;a:2:{i:0;i:553;i:1;i:1474;}i:5;...

I thought if i encode it in JSON format that it would save as i thought, but i dont understand why the output is as it is. Any ideas?

The JS code is as follows:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(tabela);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {
            text1: jsonString
        }
    });
}
```

And the PHP side is this:

```
    $text1 = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['text1']));
    $string_data = serialize($text1);
    file_put_contents("your-file.txt", $string_data);
```

Comment: You dont `stripslashes()` a json format unless encoded with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and **never** serialize user input as its a security risk.

Comment: True, sorry, but even if i remove that, it still does not work as expected...

Comment: As @Rafael says, just store it directly into the file: `file_put_contents("your-file.txt", $_POST['text1'] . PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content looks like this in the file, because you passed the array through `serialize` function. In order to "decode" file content, use `unserialize`.
If you want to have more human-readable file content, just store the JSON string in the file (`$_POST['text1']` directly) or instead of `serialize` use `json_encode` again before calling `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Thank you, your anwser helped me.

Comment: @TadejBogataj if it helped, have the courtesy to upvote and you can mark it as in answer in 15 minutes after asking your question.